# How to dynamically add a runat server button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actually, I want to know how to add it's click event.

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Go back!";
b.ID = "btn_Back";
b.Click = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

and then declare btn_Click, like:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If you're in VS2005 versions, once you hit b.Click += you'll be queried to hit TAB and declare it all automatically!

Kind regards,
Henrik.

Comment: I meant VS2008+ versions, like 2008 or 2010!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to register the event handler (using the `+=` notation):

```
b.Click += new EventHandler(NameOfHandler);
```

You will need a function called `NameOfHandler` that corresponds to the `EventHandler` delegate - that is, that takes a first parameter of type `object` and a second paremeter of type `EventArgs`:

```
public void NameOfHandler(object o, EventArgs e)
{
  // code here
}
```

Normally, in visual studio once you have typed the `+=` following the event name, tabbing a couple of times will generate the rest of the line and an empty event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Go back!";
b.ID = "btn_Back";
b.Click += new EventHandler(B_Click);
Controls.Add(b);
// ...
private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```